# How can I get the node id within the submit handler defined in hook form alter

Tags: php, drupal, variables, drupal-7

Is there a different hook I can use to get the node_id of a NEW node that is submitted?

```
function dc_project_management_form_bug_request_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['#submit'][] = 'dc_project_management_process_bug_request_milestone_submit';
}

function dc_project_management_process_bug_request_milestone_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    //NULL when submitting new node
    $form_state['values']['nid'];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The node hasn't actually been saved at that point, you need to implement [`hook_node_insert`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7):

```
function dc_project_management_node_insert($node) {
  $nid = $node->nid;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the form values in hook_node_insert?...I need that information.

Comment: As far as I remember the extra form elements are added to the `$node` object by key when it's passed to `node_save` so if you've got a form element like so: `$form['my_element'] = ...` you should be able to gain access to it with `$node->my_element` in `hook_node_insert`

Comment: While a node id is available in hook_node_insert(), it's important to note that the node hasn't yet been committed to the database (it's in the middle of a transaction), and you cannot modify the node at this point without writing directly to the database yourself.

Comment: Using the additional form elements as suggested by Clive ($node->my_element) works great for me. Thanks for the handy hint.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to retrieve the node id is to use `hook_node_insert`. However, if you wish to make modifications to the `node` object from inside this hook, you must notify Drupal of the alteration, otherwise the changes won't make it into the database transaction and will be lost.

After you're done modifying the node, call `field_attach_updates('node', $node)`. For example:

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node){
    $node->field_myfield['und'][0]['value'] = 'a new value';

    field_attach_update('node', $node);
}
```

See http://timonweb.com/how-save-yourself-some-hair-when-manipulating-node-fields for more information.